# Как перевести строку в cp1251?

Tags: кодировка, perl

Код:

```
my $encoding_name = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($email);
print "Email: $email; Encoding: $encoding_name;\n";
```

Выдача:

```
Email: artem77rue@inbox.ru; Encoding: ;
```

Попытался пропустить $email через utf8::encode, на выходе вообще пустая строка.
Соответственно, если я не знаю текущей кодировки, я не могу перевести в cp1251.

Comment: > Соответственно, если я не знаю текущей кодировки, я не могу перевести в cp1251.

вам не кажется это естественным ? ведь если гуманоид говорит на неизвестном вам языке, то без того, чтобы определить язык гуманоида, искать переводчика на русский не имеет смысла.  

есть разные частотные анализаторы кодировок, которые пытаются узнать какая кодировка у строки, но

 a. Это накладно
 b. плохо работает для коротких строк

ps: у переменной email кодировка в этом случае самая обычная - iso8859-1 или cp437, короче латиница, первые 7bit. Проверяйте строку на пустую и подставляйте iso8859-1

Comment: А насчёт перевода -- text::iconv

Comment: Но в text::iconv нужно указать и исходную кодировку. Это точно cp437? Откуда вы можете это знать?

Comment: я вижу латиницу... насчет точно, не знаю, спросите у вендора.